# Removing Spaces After Text in Cell

Tags: excel, vlookup

**Overview**

I have a list of values that I pulled from a database. These values range from B2:B39754. The values are text strings, and some contain spaces at the end which I would like to remove because I think they're causing a VLOOKUP function I'm using the range of cells with to fail (it's reporting the wrong matching value).

**What I Tried**

My first remedy was to highlight the range of cells and do a Find/Replace with a space in the 'Find' field and nothing in the 'Replace' field. No dice, spaces remained.

My second remedy was to use the TRIM() function and copy the results as values over those already in the B2:B39754 range. Again, this failed to remedy the situation.

**Additonal Info**

I have a series of address values in column B that I need to change into a more understandable description. This is the purpose of the VLOOKUP function. If you are curious, the VLOOKUP function in cell C2 is:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$G$6,2)
```

This is copied down to cell C39754.

What seems to be happening is that the VLOOKUP isn't matching the correct values from G2:G6 with the values in column B. I think this is because of the spaces after the text strings in column B, but could there be another cause for this error?

Any advice you all can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `=SUBSTITUTE(CLEAN(A1),CHAR(160),""))`

Comment: Can you do `=CODE(RIGHT(B2,1))` and see what ascii number (if any) the "space" is? A standard "space" is 32

Comment: That seems to have solved the problem with the extra spaces, but my VLOOKUP functions still aren't working like they should. Could the fact that there's colons in the text string be causing an issue?

Comment: Nope, try using false as the forth criteria in the vlookup. `=VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$G$6,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Aha! Thanks @ScottCraner, that appears to have worked. I suppose it was looking for a value that was close but not exact, and wound up returning the wrong one?

Answer (score -1):

It may also be the case that the datatype in your database "pads" to match the field size. You don't comment on the database you are using, but try changing from a "char" type to a "varchar" type for example